# content_scripts does not trigger for every match in Manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Chrome extension that would automatically block every YouTube video from being displayed by overwriting the html content of the page.

The only exceptions would be specific YouTube urls that I would have whitelisted. These urls are stored and retrieved using chrome local storage.

The script works just fine when I first try to load a YouTube video, either blocking it or displaying it if it is indeed whitelisted.
However, when I whitelist a blocked url, reload the page and browse YouTube, the next videos wont be blocked, even though they should be.

When I encounter this phenomenon, reloading the page correctly applies the whitelist.

My current content_script is as such :

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["scripts/blocker.js"],
            "matches": [
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*",
                "https://www.youtube.com/shorts/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Kindly consider substituting using the terms "allowlist" and "denylist" for "whitelist" and/or "blacklist" as Chromium source code suggests. Colors have nothing to do with allowing or denying content. You probably have to reload the extension, too.

Comment: It means the site is a SPA, which youtube is, and simply modifies DOM of the same document. You can use MutationObserver to detect it or [an event like yt-navigate-finish](/a/34100952). Note that in ether case your `matches` should be `https://www.youtube.com/*`.